# Definition of the $\hat{A}$-genus

Tags: differential-geometry

From page $50$ of [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628):

> If $E$ is a real vector bundle with covariant derivative $\nabla$ and curvature $F$, we associate to it its $\hat{A}$-genus form
> \begin{equation}
>     \hat{A}(\nabla):=\mathrm{det}^{1/2}\bigg(\frac{F/2}{\sinh{F/2}}\bigg)\in\Gamma(M,\Lambda(TM^*)).
> \end{equation}

I feel a bit betrayed, because the $\hat{A}$-genus form seems to be defined in terms of another undefined expression.

- Am I right in assuming that the definition is meant as follows: Fix $x\in M$ and choose a basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of $E_x$, consider the matrix $\Omega\in \Lambda(T_pM^*)^{n\times n}$ with $\Omega^{i}{}_{j}\in \Lambda^2(T_pM^*)\subset\Lambda(T_pM^*)$ given by
  $$\Omega^{i}{}_{j}(X,Y)=e^iF(X,Y)e_j$$
  and set
  $$\hat{A}(\nabla)_x:=\mathrm{det}^{1/2}\bigg(\frac{\Omega/2}{\sinh{\Omega/2}}\bigg)$$
  (of course we have to check that the definition is independent of the basis). But even the definition of the last expression is not entirely clear:
- First of all, note that the entries of $\Omega$ are in the even subalgebra of $\Lambda(T_pM^*)$, i.e. the determinant makes sense. I would have expected that$$\mathrm{det}^{1/2}\bigg(\frac{\Omega/2}{\sinh{\Omega/2}}\bigg):=\bigg(\mathrm{det}\bigg(\frac{\Omega/2}{\sinh{\Omega/2}}\bigg)\bigg)^{1/2}$$
  but the determinant is an element of $\Lambda(T_pM^*)$ and defining the square root is a subtle issue. Setting$$\hat{A}(\nabla)_x:=\mathrm{det}\bigg(\bigg(\frac{\Omega/2}{\sinh{\Omega/2}}\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg)$$seems much more reasonable, as this solves the issue: On the one hand, the function
  \begin{align}
  \mathbb R&\to\mathbb R\\
  x&\mapsto\sqrt{\frac{x}{\sinh{x}}}
  \end{align}
  has a nice taylor series and the other hand we dont even have to worry about convergence as $\Omega$ is nilpotent. (To do: Check consistency with $(1.36)$ for $8$-dim. manifolds.)

Comment: When it comes to characteristic classes, such expression mean that you have a formal power series in some variable $x$, and you substitute $\Omega$ which, as you note, takes away any doubts about convergence because $\Omega$ is nilpotent.

Comment: @QuaereVerum So you agree that the definition should be$$\hat{A}(\nabla):=\mathrm{det}\bigg(\bigg(\frac{F/2}{\sinh{F/2}}\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg)$$instead of$$\hat{A}(\nabla):=\bigg(\mathrm{det}\bigg(\frac{F/2}{\sinh{F/2}}\bigg)\bigg)^{1/2}?$$

Comment: No, I do not agree with that. See here if you are confused https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/ind-thm.pdf (page 34 and the preceding discussion).

Comment: @QuaereVerum Does he address my objection, namely that it is not clear how (and whether) the square root of the determinant is well defined?

Comment: Also, I seem to obtain the correct result by first taking the square root and then the determinant.

Comment: I guess that we may to try to define it by considering the taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$, but then we would either need to prove that the determinant is unipotent, or otherwise that we have convergence w.r.t. the standard topology, but this is a subtle issue since the taylor expansion only has a finite convergence radius (right?).

Comment: Yes it is addressed, see lemma 1.2.10 and the discussion right below it.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Thank you!